# Nginx reverse Proxy suddenly throws Error 502 at a specific server

Tags: nginx, nextcloud

I installed a new nextcloud (which was working for days) and was checking something (I didn't change anything!) and out of the sudden I get an Error 502 from my reverse proxy. Within LAN nextcloud still works, so it must be an error at the reverse proxy.
I use the same config file which I used for many years (just changed the IP and the domain). It is secured with certbot.

What can I do?

I think I found the problem: during installation the nextcloud created some ssl-certificates. But my ssl-certificates are already handled by my reverse-proxy. How can I remove the SSL-Stuff from my nextcloud-installation?
This is the nginx-config of the nextcloud:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
server_name cloud.mydomain.de;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/rsa-certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/rsa-certs/privkey.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/ecc-certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/ecc-certs/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/ecc-certs/chain.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
ssl_ecdh_curve X448:secp521r1:secp384r1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;
root /var/www/nextcloud;
location = /robots.txt {
allow all;
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}
location = /.well-known/carddav {
return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
}
location = /.well-known/caldav {
return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
}
client_max_body_size 10240M;
fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-f$location / {
rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
location ~ ^\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
deny all;
}
location ~ ^\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
deny all;
}
location ^~ /apps/rainloop/app/data {
deny all;
}
location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+|.+\/richdocumentscode\/proxy)\.php(?:$|\/) {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
fastcgi_pass php-handler;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_request_buffering off;
}
location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
try_files $uri/ =404;
index index.php;
}
location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
access_log off;
}
location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap|mp4|webm)$ {
try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
access_log off;
}
}
```